# Microsoft (VS2010) TFS and Excel - can not save credentials

Tags: visual-studio-2010, credentials, team-foundation-server

When I try to open xlsx file located on TFS server using Team Explorer (VS2010 Pro), naturaly it asks for credentials; and each time I check "Remember my credentials" - but credentials remains unsaved. Any workaround?